# ASP.NET Identity redirecting after login before user roles are established

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, asp.net-identity-2

My login is pretty much Identity standard code. I've added a few things to do what I need but for the most part the login code remains unedited:

```
var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(User.UserName, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: false);

switch (result)
{
    case SignInStatus.Success:
        // Store the user's supplier Id (if it exists - i.e. user is not an admin).
        using (ApplicationDbContext Context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            Session["UserId"] = User.Id;
        }

        IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
        break;
}
```

I modified the redirect in `IdentityHelper` to take the user here or there depending on his role:

```
public static void RedirectToReturnUrl(string returnUrl, HttpResponse response)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        response.Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Supplier"))
            response.Redirect("~/Members/Supplier.aspx");

        if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            response.Redirect("~/Members/Admin.aspx");

        if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Consultant"))
            response.Redirect("~/Members/Consultant.aspx");
    }
}
```

The problem is, the first time I log in with a new user (i.e. I logged in as an admin, logged out and tried to log in as a supplier), the login doesn't redirect because `HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Supplier")` returns false.

If I immediately try again with the same login credentials, it works perfectly fine so it seems to me that the system is attempting the redirect too soon and the login hasn't actually properly compiled the user information.

If this is the case, what would be the best way to slow it down so that it only attempts the redirect after the user has been properly allocated?

I feel like a simple `do...while` loop might work well enough:

```
do
{
    // Literally do nothing while the condition is true.
}
while (!HttpContext.Current.User.IsAuthenticated);
```

Seems a bit hackish though...

Answer (score 0):

Identity information store in a cookie. In your scenario, cookie has not created yet, so that `HttpContext.Current.User`does not included identity information.

Having `do while` loop does not fix your issue.

Get user role and relevant data from database using userId and redirect users according to there role rather than trying to get that from `HttpContext`.

You can achieve this using `UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user.Id,"Admin")`.